# Using addons - GRASS 6 on Win 10

Tags: grass-gis

I got binary GRASS6 installed on my laptop (Win10) . Now I am trying to use g.extension to compile r.prominence add-on but it failed. Below is the error info , can anyone give me some hints?

```
gcc -I/c/osgeo4w/usr/src/grass64/dist.i686-pc-mingw32/include -I/c/OSGeo4W/apps/gdal-16/include -I/c/OSGeo4W/include -g -O2  -I/c/OSGeo4W/apps/gdal-16/include -I/c/OSGeo4W/include  -I../dst/include    -DPACKAGE=\""grassmods"\"  -I/c/osgeo4w/usr/src/grass64/dist.i686-pc-mingw32/include -o OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32/main.o -c main.c
```

> gcc.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `cc1': No such
> file or directory

> make: *** [OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32/main.o] Error 1
> ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
> rm: cannot remove directory `C:/Users/Zac/Documents/GIS
> DataBase/demolocation/PERMANENT/.tmp/2840.0/r.prominence':
> Permission denied

Comment: GRASS6 ?? In any case, from the error message, it seems you have a problem with your mingw32 installation. Also, why mingw 32 bit?? Is your win10 32 bit??

Comment: Please consider to update to GRAS GIS 7 or later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I have updated `r.prominence` from GRASS GIS 6 version to 7 in https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/pull/574. The changes are currently under review.